# Perguntas duplicadas aparecem no mecanismo de busca?

Tags: debate, suporte

Ao pesquisar sobre **operadores ternários** no site e no google, não encontrei nenhuma pergunta/resposta sobre sua definição. Fiz então [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478650/o-que-%c3%a9-um-operador-condicional-tern%c3%a1rio) e ela foi, corretamente, sinalizada como duplicada.

O ponto é: Fiz a pergunta pois não encontrei uma que buscava a definição desse operador nem pesquisando pelo [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=operador+ternario+stackoverflow&rlz=1C1GCEU_enBR883BR883&oq=operador+ternario+stackoverflow&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j0i22i30l4.7144j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) nem pelo [próprio mecanismo de busca do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=operador+tern%C3%A1rio). Ao sinalizarem minha pergunta como duplicada, a pergunta [Como funciona este if/else com “?” e “:”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/como-funciona-este-if-else-com-e)
 foi linkada, e ela realmente responde a pergunta. Porém, como mostrado, se você pesquisa por "operador ternário" essa pergunta não aparece, então o usuário que procurar assim não encontrará a pergunta.

**Levando isso em conta, a pergunta duplicada aparece nos mecanismos de busca?** Porque, se sim, ela serveria como um redirecionamento para essa pergunta. **Se não, qual a solução para esse poblema?** Modificar a pergunta original para que usuários que buscam por "operação ternária" também a encontrem?

Comment: Uma das ideias de perguntas duplicadas é que se chegue à resposta mesmo se usarem termos diferentes na busca. Sendo assim, acho que não precisa mudar a pergunta original, pois se buscarem por "operador ternário", acharão a sua, que por sua vez tem link para as outras. Por fim, vale a leitura [deste link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), destaque para "*What we want is on the order of 4 or 5 similar-but-not-quite-the-same duplicates to cover all possible search terms and common permutations of the question*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, esse é o propósito da pergunta duplicata. Claro, o mecanismo de busca do site é uma bela porcaria :D Ok, ele ajuda em alguma coisa porque acha algumas coisas muito específicas, mas se não tiver uma palavra muito complicado, um símbolo típico para achar, as melhores buscas são feitas pelo Google mesmo e a duplicata pode ajudar muito achar o que realmente estava difícil de achar mesmo com o mecanismo sendo bom.

Comment: Entendi, fiquei na dúvida se o mecanismo excluía perguntas duplicadas da busca ou não.